# parent.frames.control.document is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a script working, but I'm getting this weird error. Any ideas what might cause it?

```
function WriteControlPage(){
    var iWriter=parent.frames.control.document;
    iWriter.open();
    iWriter.writeln("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this control object? As in:

```
parent.frames.control
```

... it's not a property of frames that I know of. Is it something you have added yourself to parent.frames? Is it something that another script has added?

Also, what is the error?